# Can't instantiate ExpandableListAdapter because it is abstract

Tags: java, android, abstract, expandablelistadapter

I am trying to use code from the internet, but when plugging said code into my personal project I am getting the following error:

> "ExpandableListAdapter" is abstract; cannot be instantiated

I have tried to do my own research for an answer to my problem but I still haven't been able to fix said problem...

Here is my code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ExpandableListView listView;
private ExpandableListAdapter AdapterMedia;
private List<String> listDataHeader;
private HashMap<String,List<String>> listHash;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.);
    initData();


    AdapterMedia = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listHash);


    listView.setAdapter(AdapterMedia);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did that code you copied also include a class called `ExpandableListAdapter`?

Comment: You cannot instantiate it because `ExpandableListAdapter` is an interface. You have to instantiate one of its implementing classes... See [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter) and have a look at the known indirect subclasses. Having a look at them as well will bring you some direct subclasses to be used, like a [`SimpleExpandableListAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleExpandableListAdapter)

Comment: I got it ! I changed the name of the class ._. my bad, thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@deHaar is correct, `ExpandableListAdapter` is **an interface and can't be directly instantiated**. I would checkout this [tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/9942/android-expandablelistview-example-tutorial) for more information.

Also, as a side note in general: `findViewById(R.id.<id>;)` needs an associated `<id>` defined from your corresponding `XML` layout: `setContentView(R.layout.<layout>);`

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom Adapter class, for example, named “MyExpandableListAdapter” and then implement `ExpandableListAdapter` in that class. You also need to implement all the methods declared in the interface.

```
public class MyExpandableListAdapter implements ExpandableListAdapter {
   @Override
   public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {...}
}
```

Check tutorials on the internet: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-expandablelistview-with-custom-adapter-baseexpandablelistadapter.html